# SELECT only distinct rows from multiple tables with one-to-many relation

Tags: sql-server

I have below 5 tables:

*VendorRegistrations*

```
------------------------------
| Id |     Company Name      |
------------------------------
|  1 |         abc           |
------------------------------
|  2 |         pqr           |
------------------------------
|  3 |         def           |
------------------------------
```

*VendorPointOfContacts*

```
-------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | ContactName |
-------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |  Contact1   |
-------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1         |  Contact2   |
-------------------------------------------
|  3 |            2         |  Contact11  |
-------------------------------------------
|  4 |            3         |  Contact21  |
-------------------------------------------
```

*VendorKeyDecisionMakers*

```
------------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | DecisionMakerName|
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |     dec1         |
------------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1         |     dec2         |
------------------------------------------------
|  3 |            2         |     dec3         |
------------------------------------------------
|  4 |            3         |     dec7         |
------------------------------------------------
```

*VendorLegalRegistrations*

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | RegistrationNumber|
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |     1             |
-------------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1         |     2             |
-------------------------------------------------
|  3 |            2         |     5             |
-------------------------------------------------
|  4 |            3         |     9             |
-------------------------------------------------
```

*VendorBusinessActivities*

```
----------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | Activity       |       
----------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |     painting   |
----------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1         |     washing    |
----------------------------------------------
|  3 |            2         |     labour     |
----------------------------------------------
|  4 |            3         |     architect  |
----------------------------------------------
```

The tables are related with one-to-many relation where one row in `VendorRegistrations` table will map to multiple rows in all other tables.

I am trying to get results using inner join but below query returns duplicate rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM VendorRegistrations a
LEFT JOIN VendorPointOfContacts b ON a.Id = b.VendorRegistrationId
LEFT JOIN VendorKeyDecisionMakers c ON a.Id = c.VendorRegistrationId
LEFT JOIN VendorLegalRegistrations d ON a.Id = d.VendorRegistrationId
LEFT JOIN VendorBusinessActivities e ON a.Id = e.VendorRegistrationId
```

The result set I'm expecting is as below:

```
ID      CompanyName   ContactName   DecisionMakerName   RegistrationNumber    Activity
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      abc           contact1      dec1                       1              painting
 1      abc           contact2      dec2                       2              washing
 2      pqr           contact11     dec3                       5              labour
 3      def           contact21     dec7                       9              architect
```

Comment: please post your sample input data, which gives this output

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @DarkRob - I have updated the input data in sample

Comment: you can try make a view from this query and select distinct from the view, other way you can add RowNumber and retrive only rowNumber=1

Comment: @marc_s - Thank you for pointing out the convention but this is just a dummy sql code that I have been trying.

Comment: @TzahiKadosh - Can you please explain with code?

Comment: What is the result set that you are actually getting? That query looks like it should work.

Comment: @shivam can you explain why you don't want in the results the row: `1 abc Contact2 dec1 1 painting`?

Comment: @forpas - It's not that I don't want, but I expect the data to be shown in order of input

Comment: @RobStreeting - I'm getting multiple rows with repeating data for VendorRegistrations Table

Comment: @shivam *I expect the data to be shown in order of input* so if you want that row where should it be placed? You did not include it in your expected results.

Comment: @shivam: `VendorLegalRegistrations` has 2 records on `VendorRegistrationId =1` similarly `VendorBusinessActivities` has 2 records on `VendorRegistrationId =1`  and in your result set registrationno 1 belong to `painting` and 2 belong to `washing`. How they are related. same case with `VendorKeyDecisionMakers`.

Comment: can you please explain how they are interrelated.

Comment: @forpas - I don't need that row to be shown coz it doesn't follow the order of input

Comment: @DarkRob - they are not interrelated.

Comment: @shivam There is no such thing as *order of input*.

Comment: then sorry dear i don't thin there is any method which create this output without any relationship. it is not 1 to many, it is many to many relationship.

Comment: @DarkRob - then is there a way to modify it to become one to many and achieve the result set?

Comment: @shivam: please check my ans.

Comment: please post your output given from above query.

Comment: @DarkRob - Sorry but I cannot share the actual output as that consists of sensitive data

Comment: @shivam: without result it is difficult to find the column duplicating your record.

Answer (score 1):

You may modify your records as per this scenario, update `VendorPointOfContacts` id column to `VendorRegistrationId`, because actually they are records of contact person. which converts your data into this

*VendorRegistrations*

```
------------------------------
| Id |     Company Name      |
------------------------------
|  1 |         abc           |
------------------------------
|  2 |         pqr           |
------------------------------
|  3 |         def           |
------------------------------
```

*VendorPointOfContacts*

```
-------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | ContactName |
-------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |  Contact1   |     ----- this id 1 is referring to another table 
-------------------------------------------
|  2 |            1         |  Contact2   |     ----- this id 2 is referring to another table 
-------------------------------------------
|  3 |            2         |  Contact11  |
-------------------------------------------
|  4 |            3         |  Contact21  |
-------------------------------------------
```

*VendorKeyDecisionMakers*

```
------------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | DecisionMakerName|
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |     dec1         |
------------------------------------------------
|  2 |            2         |     dec2         |
------------------------------------------------
|  3 |            3         |     dec3         |
------------------------------------------------
|  4 |            4         |     dec7         |
------------------------------------------------
```

*VendorLegalRegistrations*

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | RegistrationNumber|
-------------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |     1             |
-------------------------------------------------
|  2 |            2         |     2             |
-------------------------------------------------
|  3 |            3         |     5             |
-------------------------------------------------
|  4 |            4         |     9             |
-------------------------------------------------
```

*VendorBusinessActivities*

```
----------------------------------------------
| Id | VendorRegistrationId | Activity       |       
----------------------------------------------
|  1 |            1         |     painting   |
----------------------------------------------
|  2 |            2         |     washing    |
----------------------------------------------
|  3 |            3         |     labour     |
----------------------------------------------
|  4 |            4         |     architect  |
----------------------------------------------
```

After that you may write this query to get your result as;-

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM VendorRegistrations a
LEFT JOIN VendorPointOfContacts b ON a.Id = b.VendorRegistrationId
LEFT JOIN VendorKeyDecisionMakers c ON b.Id = c.VendorRegistrationId
LEFT JOIN VendorLegalRegistrations d ON b.Id = d.VendorRegistrationId
LEFT JOIN VendorBusinessActivities e ON b.Id = e.VendorRegistrationId
```

Please try this and give your feedback for same.

Comment: "VendorRegistrationId" is already the foreign key in VendorPointOfContacts table.

Comment: yes, but `VendorRegistrationId` is not going to be in foreign key relation with other table, instead of this VendorPointOfContactId is used as foreign key relation, as per your output record mentioned.

Comment: No, the "Id" mentioned in output result set is "VendorRegistrationId"

Comment: then how `contact1` is related to `painting` but not `washing`. they both have id 1

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below query (Assumption: The flow of data in other tables are similar to the demo data) :

```
SELECT  A.*, B.ContactName, C.DecisionMakerName, D.RegistrationNumber, E.Activity
FROM    @VendorRegistrations A
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, VendorRegistrationId, ContactName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) Row_ID
             FROM   @VendorPointOfContacts
    ) B ON B.VendorRegistrationId = A.ID
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, VendorRegistrationId, DecisionMakerName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) Row_ID
             FROM   @VendorKeyDecisionMakers
    ) C ON C.Row_ID = B.Row_ID AND C.VendorRegistrationId = A.ID
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, VendorRegistrationId, RegistrationNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) Row_ID
             FROM   @VendorLegalRegistrations
    ) D ON B.Row_ID = D.Row_ID AND D.VendorRegistrationId = A.ID
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, VendorRegistrationId, Activity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) Row_ID
             FROM   @VendorBusinessActivities
    ) E ON E.Row_ID = B.Row_ID AND E.VendorRegistrationId = A.ID
```

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c93e8a3920b18236d23ba17425ea5fc)**

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried this and it returns just one row.

Comment: Use the demo to check the output of the query.

Comment: I tried removing the last "INNER JOIN" from the query and it returned the expected output. Seems the problem is due to "VendorBusinessActivities" table as it contains more rows per VendorRegistration in actual data than other tables